# Is it possible to reset TCP-connections if interface goes down in Linux?

Tags: linux-networking

Today I was trolled^Wasked to implement resetting TCP connection if internet is disconnected, like Windows® does by resetting all related TCP connection when interface goes down. So, question is: is it possible to make linux' TCP stack to behave like Windows does and reset connections if I, for example, unplug ethernet cable?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but I will say I find that behavior slightly undesirable (if I accidentally unplug my network cable and plug it back in quickly 99% of the time all my SSH sessions are still alive - yes it's happened to me a few times, and if all my connections reset that would suck :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but there is one username that really WANTS such behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tcpkill` command looks promising -- I suppose you could hook it in the interface-down event scripts...

[Cribbed from here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/kill-tcp-connection-using-linux-netstat.php)

Comment: It is one of possible solutions, but not accurate one :)

Comment: Hm, what doesn't it do that you're looking for?

Comment: It requires to write custom script that lists tcp connections and drops them selectively. More accurate would be if kernel itself will drop connections that relied on interface, but I'm not sure that linux kernel has such option.

Comment: The script isn't that hard -- Grab the IP off the interface & kill every connection involving that IP (2 lines, maybe 3).  You could get more involved if you want, but don't have to. I agree if someone comes up with a kernel option that's probably a better way to go though.